Identity Validation stuck in "In Progress" status
We are using Azure Code Signing from its very beginning as a private beta and we continue to use it as a premium account memeber of the Trusted Signing service now in public beta.
We have created new Identity for our Trusted Signing account, and successfuly submitted for validation. Then we received the email verification from Microsoft and successfully verified the email account. But the validation stays in "In Progress" for over 24 hours. No email recieved. This is not the best user experiance I'd expect from a paid service.
The expectation was that the validation is a fully automated process or workflow, where we are kept aware of the current status (other than the ambigous "In Progress" phrase) and what to expect next in the workflow.
How long does this validation process takes place and what should we expect next?

I believe you are all set or was there another validation request that was sent. Processing time information is in here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/trusted-signing/quickstart?tabs=registerrp-portal%2Caccount-portal%2Ccertificateprofile-portal%2Cdeleteresources-portal#important-information-for-public-identity-validation

Yes - after approaching the team, the request had been processed and approved. I hope the status of future requests will reflect the actual steps more or less and perhaps it will be best to add a link to a document with the processing time. Thanks!

Great and yes, the QuickStart guide has the processing time.
